# Aligning a Text and TextField inside the Section of a Form

Tags: swiftui

Another simple SwiftUI tasks that is causing me more trouble than it should.

I can't figure a way to align the Text and TextField correctly.

None of the HSTack alignment seem to yield acceptable results.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SignIn: View {
    @State var email: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Sign In")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Form {
                Section {
                    HStack {
                        Text("ID")
                        TextField("Email", text: $email)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SignIn_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SignIn()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use another TextField instead of a Text:

```swift
HStack {
    TextField("", text: .constant("ID"))
        .fixedSize()
        .disabled(true)
    TextField("Email", text: $email)
    Spacer()

}
```

It's kinda ugly though.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned trying different HStack alignments, did you try `.firstTextBaseline` or `.lastTextBaseline`? Both of these align the Text and TextField correctly for me. So that line becomes

```
HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline) {
```

[Screenshot of Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT3ib.png)

Full code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SignIn: View {
    @State var email: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Sign In")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Form {
                Section {
                    HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline) {
                        Text("ID")
                        TextField("Email", text: $email)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SignIn_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SignIn()
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, and it works at default font sizes.  But when the system font size is smaller or larger than the default, the Text and TextField do not align.  I have submitted bug [FB7584702](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/7584702) to Apple about this.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue, and the answer is simpler than I thought. I ended up adding the modifier .aspectRatio(.fit) and that fixed it for me.

Hope this helps!